# MVC custom Route not works for Post call in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

i have declare custom route in route.config in mvc and it is working for get verbs but not works for post verb.
i am trying to call post verb using jquery but it does not works.

Can you help me to short out this issue.

Route.config:

```
routes.MapRoute("Defualt", "MyController", new { Controller = "Post", Action = "index", id=UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Controller.cs:

```
public class PostController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    //[Route("Mycontroller/Post")]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string name)
    {
        PersonModel person = new PersonModel
        {
            Name = name,
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
        };
        return Json(person);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model MvcWithJquery.Models.PersonModel
@{
Layout = null;
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Current Time" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MyController/Post/AjaxMethod",
                    data: '{name: "' + $("#txtName").val() + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Hello: " + response.Name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run the program and press the button,below error comes:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meip9.png)

Comment: Assuming `MyController` is an area name, try using this `MapRoute`: `routes.MapRoute("Default", "MyController/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { Controller = "Post", Action = "index", id=UrlParameter.Optional });`. JSON POST with AJAX seems work but it doesn't find route path for action method given by `url`.

Answer (score 0):

In your route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Defualt", "MyController", new { Controller = "Post", Action = "index", id=UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The second parameter is the `url` pattern, which you have defined as `MyController`. Therefore, the only URL that can access this route is `/MyController`.

So, to make it work you either need to change your AJAX call to the correct URL...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Current Time" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MyController",
                    data: '{name: "' + $("#txtName").val() + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Hello: " + response.Name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

...or, you need to change the URL to match your AJAX call.

```
routes.MapRoute("Defualt", "MyController/Post/{action}", new { Controller = "Post", action = "index", id=UrlParameter.Optional });
```

On a side note, it doesn't make much sense to have an optional `id` parameter in a route that cannot accept `{id}` through the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute("Defualt", "MyController/Post/{action}", new { Controller = "Post", action = "index" });
```